# How to map columns of two dfs containing sentences using spacy or nlp

Tags: dataframe, machine-learning, nlp, nltk, spacy

There are two input tables (or df). each contains an id and corresponding descriptions. That is table1 contains id1 description1 and table2 contains id2 and description2. I have to compare descriptions 1 and 2. And map rows of table 1 with matching rows of table 2(there will be more than one row in table 2 which is matching to table 1's row). And the final output table contains all four columns. I applied NLP to the raw dataset. Which prediction algorithm I have to select?

Answer (score 0):

Is it some kind of assignment where there are two product descriptions in a different data frame and you have to map and make relation in between them ?

Comment: I have to create a model.The model have to read both descriptions and map them.